# Any HAVAL hash implementation on Android?

Tags: java, android, hash

Is there any native or 3rd party implementations of [HAVAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAVAL) hashing on Android SDK (or some open-source Java library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GNU Crypto](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/) seems to include [Haval](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-crypto/manual/api/gnu/crypto/hash/Haval.html) in its selection of algorithms.